# convert nsmanganedobject to array to find average of array

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, appdelegate, nsfetchrequest

My code below fetches a string from core data and finds the sum of the array.I want to know find the average of all of the numbers in the array by dividing the sum by how many items are in the array. I just need someone to build off of this by dividing the amount of numbers by the sum that I have already found.

```
 func performAction() {
    let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Data")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        var retrievedData = [Double]()
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            if let value = data.value(forKey: "ee") as? String {
                retrievedData.append(Double(value) ?? 0)
            }
        }

        let arraySum = retrievedData.reduce(0, +)
        print(arraySum)

    } catch {

        print("Failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: `arraySum/retrievedData.count` could work?

Comment: That works got to add double in front of the denominator .

Comment: how would I be able to find the lowest number in the arraySum array?